# How to follow TDD principles with class using factories

Tags: c#, tdd, factory

I have trying to motivate my team to enhance our development skills by following TDD. It's a great experience but at some of points I noticed most of them stopped doing that due the problems below:

1/ We are developing "brokers" triggered when something happens and designed to perform a set of actions (send emails, process the data, convert files...).

2/ All brokers are loaded when the application starts thanks to a simple `Activator.CreateInstance(brokerType)`.

3/ One of our brokers is supposed to extract records from an excel file and try find associated records in a DB. To do so we just use the code below:

```
public void Process(string file)
{
    using (var sun = new SunSystemExcelDataSource(ExcelDatasourceFactory.Create(file)))
    {//...}
}
```

This code calls a factory returning a class (inheriting from `IExcelSource`) able to parse the specified excel file (XLS vs XLSX) and then it is passed as a parameter to the `SunSystemExcelDataSource`'s constructor.

Question: This method becomes hardly testable. I was wondering if you could give us some tips to improve code test-ability.

**Generally speaking how do test classes that rely on factories to build themselves?**

Code:

```
public void Initialize(ILog log, AppSettings settings)
{
    _log = log;
    _hrdb = DbDatasourceFactory.CreateHrdbDatasource(settings.HrdbConnectionString);
    _processor = new K2Processor(settings.SettlePaymentWorkflow);
    _sunFolderPath = settings.SunSystemExcelFolderPath;
}
```

Comment: The Factory should not be a Static Type, but get dependency injected as well. This way, you mock the Factory as well, which then returns the testable object.

Comment: Microsoft shims and fakes can mock static methods. We can use that,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moq library doesn't support Static methods. But we can use Microsoft Shims and Fakes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

We can still use Moq, but for that we have to modify the code to something like this,

```
public void Initialize(ILog log, AppSettings settings)
{
    Initialize(log, settings, DbDatasourceFactory.CreateHrdbDatasource(settings.HrdbConnectionString);
}

// Unit-test this method,
internal void Initialize(ILog log, AppSettings settings, HrdbDataSource hrdbDataSource)
{
    _log = log;
    _hrdb = hrdbDataSource;
    _processor = new K2Processor(settings.SettlePaymentWorkflow);
    _sunFolderPath = settings.SunSystemExcelFolderPath;
}
```